# How can I "imagine" the users movement?

Tags: android

I don't know how to explain this.

But take Android desktop as an example.

When you move your finger, you move the whole desktop, until a point that you're on the next desktop. So as you can see, if you move the screen, for about 51% to the right, when you leave your finger off the screen, it will go to the right screen, and if you just moved the screen 40ish percent, it will be back on the same screen.

How is this pattern called?

Some sort of "predicting" users movements.

Comment: I think you just described how it works :)

Comment: [look into ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) that is an AdapterView included with the support lib that has the behavior that you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are talking about the [Location Within](http://4ourth.com/wiki/Location%20Within) pattern:

[image: Location Within pattern from mobile UI pattern catalog by Steven Hoober and Eric Berkman]

> **Problem:**
>   You must describe the location within a series of screens which
>   contain alternate views, or which continue the display of a set of
>   content.
>
> **Solution:**
>   When several screens of similar or continuous information are
>   presented with an organic access method, an indicator is usually
>   required so the user understands their position within the system.

Other sources might call such a thing "carousel" or "slideshow".

**Updated answer:**
After reading more carefully, "Location Within" might only reference the page position indicators that show which screen is currently in view. Perhaps just the [Slideshow](http://4ourth.com/wiki/Slideshow) or [Film Strip](http://4ourth.com/wiki/Film%20Strip) patterns describe more exactly what you mean.

As FoamyGuy pointed out in a comment, [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) is the way to implement "slideshows" in Android.
Additionally, [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) provides flexible options to display the page position indicators ("Location Within" pattern)